# Getting Exception of System.IO.FileNotFoundException in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, gif

now i am doing playing gif image in my application in windows phone 7, i tried this code  xml

```
  `xmlns:imagetools="clr-namespace:ImageTools.Controls;assembly=ImageTools.Controls" '
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <imagetools:ImageConverter x:Key="ImageConverter" />
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>



`<imagetools:AnimatedImage Source="{Binding ImageSource, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" /`>
```

and c#

```
 try
            {
                ImageSource = new Uri("file:///C:/Users/sram.I-WAVES/Desktop/S&L_BB/Dice%20anim/dice_anim_1.gif", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                ImageTools.IO.Decoders.AddDecoder<ImageTools.IO.IImageDecoder>();
                this.DataContext = this;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

but it throws the Exception of like "Could not load 'System.Diagnostic.Contracts.ContractFailurekind' from assembly 'mscorlib, version=3.7.0.0. Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=969DB8053D3322AC'". Please tell me how to solve this problem and what should i do to play the gif image in windows phone

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: 1/ You're supposed to call `AddDecoder<GifDecoder>`, not `AddDecoder<IImageDecoder>`. 2/ `file:///` paths won't work on Windows Phone. 3/ Make sure you're using the Windows Phone version of ImageTools

Comment: Thank u for ur Reply, now working well if i give image from server side  but i want to work from local path image that mean load the image from inside the project like jpeg or png format image, if i give uri "file:///C:/Users/sram.I-WAVES/Desktop/S&L_BB/Dice%20anim/dice_anim_1.gif" it throws the Exception like "exception occurred during a WebClient request. how to solve this problem and how to show the image from inside the project ? please help me

Answer (score 3):

Add the image to the project, set its `BuildAction` to `Content` and the use a relartive path to the image:

```cs
ImageSource = new Uri("/path-to-the-image-inside-the-project/dice_anim_1.gif", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Comment: but one problem is occurring here, that is sometimes gif images will not be animated something get stuck during running on the simulater and sometimes moving but not fully. what is the problem is going on?, i don't know pls help me

Comment: pls tell me how to stop with last frame of gif image during run time in windows phone 7

Comment: @siva mark this question as answered and ask further questions in a new thread, you will find help more easily